# Winforms MouseEventArgs - How can I get a click modifier like control-click or alt-click?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to detect if a combobox was clicked by control click. Using Winforms.

If I just try capturing MouseEventArgs I don't see any modifiers.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Control.ModifierKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys) -- What has WPF to do with this?

Comment: I assume if someone's done WPF they might know about winforms as well.

Comment: That's not a valid assumption and, even if it was, so what? The tags are to specify what your question is about. It's not about WEPF, so don't lie to people. People watch a tag because they are interested in questions on that subject. It's not for you to waste people's time by tricking them into thinking that your question is about something it is not.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in any event method.

```
    if (Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control) Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Ctrl+Click")
    end if
```